# Power Automate, "Filter Query" in Get Items to get Date = Today

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

I am trying to use "Filter Query" to filter my "Get Items" so it only returns the items created today.

Here is what I am trying, "Modified" is the column of my dates.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get this?